# Having data stored across tables representing individual data types - Why is it wrong?

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

Say I have lots of time to waste and decide to make a database where information is not stored as entities but in separate inter-related tables representing `INT`,`VARCHAR`,`DATE`,`TEXT`, etc types.

It would be such a revolution to never have to design a database structure ever again except that the fact no-one else has done it probably indicates it's not a good idea :p

So why is this a bad design ? What principles is this going against ? What issues could it cause from a practical point of view with a relational database ?

P.S: This is for the learning exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't you separate out the fields from your tables based on their data types?  Well, there are two reasons, one philosophical, and one practical.

### Philosophically, you're breaking normalization

A properly normalized database will have different tables for different THINGS, with each table having all fields necessary and unique for that specific "thing."  If the only way to find the make, model, color, mileage, manufacture date, and purchase date of a given car in my CarCollectionDatabase is to join meaningless keys on three tables demarked by data-type, then my database has almost zero discoverablity and no real cohesion.

If you designed a database like that, you'd find writing queries and debugging statements would be obnoxiously tiresome.  Which is kind of the reason you'd use a relational database in the first place.

(And, really, that will make writing queries WAY harder.)

### Practically, databases don't work that way.

Every database engine or data-storage mechanism i've ever seen is simply not meant to be used with that level of abstraction.  Whatever engine you had, I don't know how you'd get around essentially doubling your data design with fields.  And with a five-fold increase in row count, you'd have a massive increase in index size, to the point that once you get a few million rows your indexes wouldn't actually help.

If you tried to design a database like that, you'd find that even if you didn't mind the headache, you'd wind up with slower performance.  Instead of 1,000,000 rows with 20 fields, you'd have that one table with just as many fields, and some 5-6 extra tables with 1,000,000+ entries each.  And even if you optimized that away, your indexes would be larger, and larger indexes run slower.

---

Of course, those two ONLY apply if you're actually talking about databases.  There's no reason, for example, that an application can't serialize to a text file of some sort (JSON, XML, etc.) and never write to a database.

And just because your application needs to store SQL data doesn't mean that you need to store everything, or can't use homogenous and generic tables.  An Access-like application that lets user define their own "tables" might very well keep each field on a distinct row... although in that case your database's THINGS would be those tables and their fields.  (And it wouldn't run as fast as a natively written database.)